# reading and writing from a same binary file in c++

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I am trying to write a link list to a binary file and then to read it back when program starts.

I have the following code written for the same:

```
class Node
{
    private:
        int pos;
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;

        friend class Linklist;

    public:
        Node(int d):data(d),pos(-1),next(NULL),prev(NULL)
        {}  

};
#include <new>
#include <sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include"linklist.h"

bool Linklist::insert(int data, bool updateDisk)
{
    if(isExist(data))
    {
        std::cout<<"Tried to insert duplicate data";
        return false;
    }

    Node *temp  = new (std::nothrow) Node(data);
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
       return false;
    }

    if(tail == NULL)
    {
        tail = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail = temp;
    }

    if(updateDisk)
    {
        tail->pos = nextPosition++;
        updateAdditionOnDisk(tail);
    }
}

bool Linklist::insert(int data, int location)
{
    if(isExist(data))
    {
        return false;
    }

    Node *temp  = new (std::nothrow) Node(data);
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
       return false;
    }

    Node *it = head;
    while(it != NULL)
    {
        if(it->pos > location)
        {
            break;
        }
        it = it->next;
    }

    if(it)
    {
        temp->prev = it->prev;
        temp->next = it;
        it->prev->next = temp;
        it->prev = temp;
    }

    //tail->position = updateAdditionOnDisk(data, nextAvailablePos);
}

bool Linklist::erase(int data)
{
    if(tail == NULL)
        return false;

    Node *temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == data)
        {
            //nextAvailablePos = updateDeletionOnDisk(temp->position, nextAvailablePos);
            if(temp == head)
            {
                if(head->next)
                {
                    head = head->next;
                    head->prev = NULL;
                    delete temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    delete head;
                    head = NULL;
                    tail = NULL;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else if(temp == tail)
            {
                if(head == tail)
                {
                    delete head;
                    head = NULL;
                    tail = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    tail = tail->prev;
                    tail->next = NULL;
                    delete temp;
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                delete temp;
                return true;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    return false;
}

bool Linklist::isExist(int data)
{
    Node *temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {

       if(temp->data == data)
       {
            return true;
       }
       temp = temp->next;

    }
    return false;
}

void Linklist::display( )
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<temp->data;
        if(temp->next)
        {
            std::cout<<"-->";
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int Linklist::updateAdditionOnDisk(Node *node)
{
    oFile.seekp (0, std::ios::beg);
    oFile.write( (char*)&nextPosition, sizeof(int) );
    oFile.flush();

    int count = 0,pos = 0;
    bool inserted = false;
    Node n(-1);
    iFile.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
    iFile.read((char*)&pos, sizeof(int));
    while(!iFile.eof())
    {
        std::cout<<"iFile is good";
        if(n.pos == -1)
        {
            oFile.seekp(sizeof(int) + (sizeof(Node) * count) , std::ios::beg);
            oFile.write( (char*)node, sizeof(Node) );
            oFile.flush();
            inserted = true;
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    if(!inserted)
    {
        oFile.seekp(sizeof(int), std::ios::beg);
        oFile.write( (char*)node, sizeof(Node) );
        oFile.flush();
    }
}

int Linklist::updateDeletionOnDisk(int data)
{
    int temp = nextPosition + 1;
    oFile.seekp (0, std::ios::beg);
    oFile.write( (char*)&nextPosition, sizeof(int) );
    oFile.flush();

    int count = 0,pos = 0;
    bool inserted = false;
    Node n(-1);
    n.pos = -1;
    iFile.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
    iFile.read((char*)&pos, sizeof(int));
    while(!iFile.eof())
    {
        std::cout<<"iFile is good";
        iFile.read((char*)&n, sizeof(int));
        if(n.data == data)
        {
            n.pos = -1;
            oFile.seekp(sizeof(int) + (sizeof(Node) * count) , std::ios::beg);
            oFile.write( (char*)&n, sizeof(Node) );
            oFile.flush();
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

}

void Linklist::createListFromFile ()
{
     Node n(-1);

     iFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
     if(!iFile.eof())
     {
         iFile.read((char*)&nextPosition, sizeof(int));
        while(!iFile.eof())
        {
            iFile.read((char*)&n, sizeof(Node));
        }

     }

}

Linklist::~Linklist()
{
    while(head)
    {
       Node * temp = head;
       head = head->next;
       delete temp;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    char choice;
    int data;

    Linklist l;

    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\nSelect Opration to performed on LinkList"<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "1 Insert "<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "2 Delete "<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "3 IsExist "<<std::endl;
        std::cout << "4 Display "<<std::endl;
     }

}

Linklist::~Linklist()
{
    while(head)
    {
       Node * temp = head;
       head = head->next;
       delete temp;
    }
}
```

but the code is giving me garbage output.

Can someone please point at mistakes that I might have in the code.

thanks

Comment: ifstream and ofstream member variables

Comment: At least post the definition of `Node`. I'm willing to bet it's not POD. Which means that either you're not saving what you need at all, or you're invoking _undefined behaviour_ as if it was going out of style. (Possibly both)

Comment: Have you examined the contents of the file with a hex browser to see if it got written correctly?

Comment: thanks sehe for looking into this. I have editied the post

Comment: examined content with a hex browser and content looked wrong but I can not figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

In function `Linklist::updateAdditionOnDisk()`, what is the purpose of the local variable `n`?  You initialize it and then inspect it but never change its value.  Perhaps you should eliminate it and just look at `node`?  (Which by the way should be declared as a pointer to `const Node` so you can't modify a `Node` instance by mistake when you save it).

The more I look at `Linklist::updateAdditionOnDisk()` the more confused I get.  `pos` is a local variable, and it will be read from the output file every time the function is called; it's never used or modified.  You have a loop that will loop forever until `n.pos` has a value other than `-1`; it also checks `iFile.eof()` but the loop doesn't read from `iFile` so that check will always succeed or always fail.  `count` is a local variable, always starting at 0... that may be your problem actually.  Consider this line:

```
oFile.seekp(sizeof(int) + (sizeof(Node) * count) , std::ios::beg);
```

This uses `count` to seek within the output file.  But `count` will always be 0, so this will just keep seeking to the start of the file and overwriting the previous record.  Maybe you wanted `pos` instead of `count` here?  Or maybe `node.pos`?

Have you tried single-stepping your program in a debugger and watching what it does?  For that matter, have it print values of variables like `count` on each pass and watch how it seeks in the output file.

And, if you are just trying to solve the problem of storing values, you might want to either store just the integer values (prefixed by a count) or use an already-written, already-debugged library that stores your data for you (in JSON format, or HDF5 format, or even an SQLite database file).

`Linklist::insert()` can fail.  If the `location` is ever too large for any `Node` instance in the list, then the `while` loop will run to the end, leaving `it` set to `NULL` and then nothing gets inserted.  Also, you don't have `return true` anywhere to signal successful add.

`Linklist::createListFromFile()` never calls `insert()`.  So it doesn't actually build a linked list.  The code you had posted earlier, I think, was calling `insert()` but this code isn't calling it.

Sorry but I don't have any more time for this.  Here are some guideline-type suggestions:

- Your function to write a linked list to disk shouldn't need to seek at all.  Just write the number of data records, followed by all the records.
- Your function to read a linked list from disk shouldn't need to seek at all.  Just read the number of data records, then loop until you have read that many records from the disk, calling `insert()` on each value read from disk.
- You call `flush()` frequently, but you shouldn't need to do that at all.  Just write all your records, and then close the output file.
- Your function to write to disk should use a `const` pointer.  Writing data to disk shouldn't change the data, so declare your intentions by using `const`.
- Write the simplest code that can possibly work, and then test it and make sure it works the way you want it to work.  Then, add more features to it.  I suggest you write a test program that makes a linked list containing the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and single-step to watch it save that list to disk and then read it and build a new linked list from the disk file.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: thanks steveha but value of pointers does not matter. If you see I do an insert on node.data to make sure I am not using the pointer values that you mentioned. Problem is I am getting garbage while reading the file from disk

Comment: n act as a placeholder for data read from file so that correct position for node can be determined

Comment: i am just trying to learn how file i/o in c++ work. I have done as you have suggested. Infact therewere logs in the entire program which I delete before posting it here. I get correct values just before file.writ but when I try to read from the file i receive garbage values

Comment: I think use of count is correct. I want to seek a node where the pos(istion) is -1 and I want to write the node passed to function to the file and thus after first read count will be one and seek will return me starting of the file (+ 1 one integer) but after every read value of count will be incremented. There are local variables because I have to seek the correct location in file to insert data for that I have to traverse nodes one by one

Comment: I really don't think the use of `count` is correct.  I don't understand what it is counting.  The loop will run forever if `iFile.eof()` is true and `n.pos()` is not -1, because nothing in the loop reads from `iFile` or modifies `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code instantiates an instance of `Linkedlist`, but does only (implicitely) call its constructor and destructor.

And your code does not call anything else.

You have not provided full declaration of class `Linkedlist`. So we may just guess. And while guessing about your code, we may guess a lot of things. But probably nothing that may help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code, so I didn't even try to guess what it is supposed to do. But by skimming over it, I found theese two lines:

```
oFile.write( (char*)node, sizeof(Node) );
```

and

```
iFile.read((char*)&n, sizeof(Node));
```

You are writing/reading objects of `Node` type, but `Node` contains pointers!! Storing and retriving pointers in files doesn't make any sense!